# Bluetooth connected but not sending data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm working on a project connecting my Android phone to an Arduino bluetooth transceiver. It works fine until the phone goes into suspend (sleep?) mode; when that happens, the bluetooth connection I establish seems to still exist, but no data is transferred. I'm using Android Sdk 30.

Here's what I do: I have a UI list with BT devices for the user to choose; after one is selected, this is called to connect:

```
// in my BluetoothService class
private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;

public void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        bluetoothDevice = device;
        String uuid = getString(R.string.bluetooth_uuid);
        bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(uuid));
        bluetoothSocket.connect();
        if (bluetoothSocket.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "connected to " + device + " with socket " + bluetoothSocket);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "still not connected to " + device + " with socket " + bluetoothSocket);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to connect to device", e);
    }
}
```

So again, this works fine; the connection is established and data is sent/received.

Now, I send data every 30 seconds, and on the receiver side light an led until 60 seconds have passed with no data received.

```
private ScheduledFuture<?> sendScheduler; // canceled in onDestroy()
public void onCreate() {
    sendScheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        sendData(lastLevelSent); // i can post sendData, but it works in normal state
    }, 30, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Now when the phone goes into sleep (ie I press the power button once), the led turns off after 60 seconds, ie no data is being received. However, the connection itself seems to still be established (I can tell by how the receiver led blinks).

When I wake the device back up, it does not resume sending data. The disconnect button in my app doesn't work (`bluetoothSocket.close()`), and trying to connect to the device again doesn't either. I have to kill the app, then I can disconnect.

The check I'm using whether the connection is still valid is `bluetoothSocket != null && bluetoothSocket.isConnected()`.

I did add my app to the "don't put into standby" in the Android settings.

So how can I either convince the app to continue sending data while in sleep mode, or at least reliably check the connection status?